# After sorting a list and storing in variable does not returning the sorted list when print statement is used

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[1,2,4,54,1,7]
b=a.sort()
print(b)
```

Output is `None`

I expected the sorted result but it is not returning anything.

Comment: `print(a)`. `.sort()` sorts in-place and returns `None` which is Python's way of saying nothing.

Comment: If you want to store the sorted array into a new list, use `b = sorted(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

python `list.sort()` sorts the list in place. IE when you do `a.sort()` it changes `a` and does not return data to assign to a new variable.

```
a=[1,2,4,54,1,7]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

The other option is you can use the `sorted()` function and that will return a new list of numbers that are sorted

```py
a = [1,2,4,54,1,7]
b = sorted(a)
print(b)
```

[Here is a python doc on some sorting options](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Why not just do `print(a)` in the first snippet?

Comment: No reason. I just defaulted to saving a line when I should not have.